# Given a point $c \in \mathbb{R}^n$, find the nearest point $d \in [a_1, b_1] \times \cdots \times [a_n, b_n]$ to $c$.

Tags: general-topology, optimization

> Given a point $c = (c_1, \cdots, c_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n - [a_1, b_1] \times \cdots \times [a_n, b_n]$, find the nearest point $d = (d_1, \cdots, d_n) \in [a_1, b_1] \times \cdots \times [a_n, b_n]$ to $c$.

There is the following problem in a book I am reading now.
After I solved the problem as follows, I am interested in the above problem.
Please answer the above problem.

> Show that $[a_1, b_1] \times \cdots \times [a_n, b_n]$ is a closed set of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Proof:

Let $c = (c_1, \cdots, c_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n - [a_1, b_1] \times \cdots \times [a_n, b_n]$. Then, there is an integer $i \in \{1, \cdots, n\}$ such that $c_i \notin [a_i, b_i]$.

Let $$\epsilon := \begin{cases} a_i-c_i & c_i < a_i \\ c_i-b_i & 
b_i < c_i \end{cases}.$$

If $\sqrt{(x_1-c_1)^2 + \cdots + (x_n-c_n)^2} < \epsilon$, then $|x_i - c_i| \leq \sqrt{(x_1-c_1)^2 + \cdots + (x_n-c_n)^2} < \epsilon$.

So, $c_i - \epsilon < x_i < c_i + \epsilon$.

If $c_i < a_i$, then $x_i < c_i + \epsilon = c_i + (a_i - c_i) = a_i$.

If $b_i < c_i$, then $b_i = c_i - (c_i - b_i) = c_i - \epsilon < x_i$.

So, $x_i \notin [a_i, b_i]$.

So, $(x_1, \cdots, x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n - [a_1, b_1] \times \cdots \times [a_n, b_n]$.

This proves that $\mathbb{R}^n - [a_1, b_1] \times \cdots \times [a_n, b_n]$ is an open set.

So, $[a_1, b_1] \times \cdots \times [a_n, b_n]$ is a closed set.

Comment: Find $d_1 \in [a_1,b_1]$ which minimizes $|d_1-c_1|\,$. Repeat.

Comment: Hint: you can adjust $d_1$ through $d_n$ independently to minimize $|c_i - d_i|$ subject to the constraint $d_i \in [a_i, b_i]$.  That then minimizes $\lVert c - d \rVert = \left( \sum_{i=1}^n |c_i - d_i|^2 \right)^{1/2}$.

Comment: @dxiv I guess I misread the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much, Mr. dxiv, Mr. Daniel Schepler.